# Converting infinite base-k expansions into base-j expansions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I understood the method of transforming a finite sized base-k numbers to another base (j) through the use of successive divisions

For example

$$12_{10} = 12/2 + 0*2^0 = 6/2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0 = 3/2 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0 =  1100_2$$

But what about generalizing this to consider infinite expansions in some base?

I can't seem to reason a good strategy involving remainders for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never write down all of an infinite expansion -- the best you can hope for is to approximate the number as closely as you need for a particular purpose, or, in some cases, to specify a pattern that repeats ad infinitum in the digits.

With this in mind, converting an infinite expansion from base $k$ to base $j$ is no more problematic then writing down the expansion in the first place. You can determine it up to any given digit after the [radix point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point) by performing your procedure for finite expansions on a truncation of your base $k$ expansion.

Let me elaborate: say that you have a number $x$, represented in base $k$ by a possibly infinite expansion, which you can compute to any finite number of digits after the radix point (for instance $(.3333....)_{10}$ represents the number $\frac{1}{3}$, and given any natural number $m$ you can compute its base $10$ expansion to $m$ digits after the radix point).

To approximate $x$ in base $j$, you first truncate the base $k$ expansion of $x$ to include $m$ places after the radix point. That is, you approximate $x$ by a string of digits $(a_na_{n-1}.. a_0.b_1...b_m)_k$. Note that the number $y$ represented by this approximation differs from $x$ at most $k^{-m}$.

Now, suppose that you convert your expansion for $y$ from base $k$ to base $j$. How many digits of $y$ in base $j$ match those of $x$ in base $j$? To answer this, suppose that $l$ is the maximal natural number so that $j^l$ divides $k^m$. It's easy to see that your base $j$ expansion of $y$ matches that of $x$ at least up to the $(l-1)$-st digit after the radix point. You can run this argument backwards to get as many digits as you like of the expansion for $x$ in a given base, if that's what you are looking to do.

Note that numbers with finite expansions in one base need not have finite expansions in another, and vice versa: 
$$(.3333333....)_{10} = (.1)_{3}.$$

So, really, the only way to avoid this "infinity problem" when converting between basis is to restrict yourself to whole numbers.